# C++ DirectX application getting unknown message code

Tags: c++, windows, directx

I am attempting to make a C++ DirectX application for Windows, but I can't seem to make it past the MSDN tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dgetstarted/getting-started-with-a-directx-game). I copied everything it says to do, and my application opens, but it is unresponsive. When I output the message my WndProc function is receiving, it is 799, which doesn't seem to be a valid Windows message code. If anyone has ever gotten that code before and knows what it means, I would love to hear it. Thanks!

EDIT: I figured it out. I was using PM_NOREMOVE in PeekMessage, which was what was in the tutorial, but using PM_REMOVE instead fixed the problem.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with how you copied the code, or how your build environment is set up.  Would you post the code you're compiling, and show us how you're building your application?  And if you're copy-pasting directly from the tutorial, let us know what's your code and if you've modified any of it.

Comment: 799 is 0x31f which is WM_DWMNCRENDERINGCHANGED. But that isn't particularly relevant, when you get a message you aren't specifically handling you should just pass it to DefWindowProc anyway without caring about what it is.

Comment: You may want to look at the **directx-vs-templates** on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) which provides a basic message loop, Direct3D device, and swapchain for Win32 or UWP.